# Parallelism in Asyncronous Sockets in a Client - C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, client

I am working on a system that has to request information from about 200 'sensors' usig TCP, so basically a client with a ton of servers. Each sensor sends an unknown number of messages to which I must reply with ACK every time after 0,1 seconds, the last ACK will get no reply from the sensor. The last message is identified as such by a tag.  I am to request information with a delay of 0,5 seconds after the last received message.

This is how I work with one sensor:

First, the information request:

```
public void Request(string request)
    { 
        Send_msg(request, this.EndPoint);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        buffer_rcvr = new byte[MaxSizebuffer];

        try
        {
            IAresult3 = socketPC_BB.BeginReceive(buffer_rcvr, 0, MaxSizebuffer, socketFlags, out  errorCode, Package_receive, state);
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            (Adds error to log)
        }   


private void Send_msg(string str_frame, EndPoint BB_ip_and_port)
    {

        try
        {
            IAresult2 = this.socketPC_BB.BeginSend(FrameToByte_Encoder(str_frame), 0, str_frame.Length, socketFlags, callback, state);
            socketPC_BB.EndSend(IAresult2);
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            (Adds error to log)
        }         
    }
```

And this is how I listen:

```
void Package_receive(IAsyncResult answer)
    {

        Msg= ProcessMessage(ByteToFrame_Decoder(buffer_rcvr));

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        this.Send_msg(ACK, this.EndPoint);

        try
        {
            IAresult3 = this.socket.BeginReceive(buffer_rcvr, 0, MaxSizebuffer, socketFlags, out errorCode, Package_receive, state);

        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            (Adds error to log)
        }
    }
```

So this works for one sensor somehow. I did not write most of this code and am still wondering how it manages to work so well without ever calling EndReceive. (I suspect it works with a timeout - this.socket.ReceiveTimeout = 3000;)

My main question is whether creating multiple sockets with a list of IPs and ports and calling these methods would add to the delay of each individual sensor or whether the callback is perfectly asynchronous and they'd work in parallel in different threads. Do I need to use threadsafe methods inside the callback to add all the data to a list?
And most importantly: would it be wise or a waste of energy to manually create individual threads for each socket to continue polling without the delay in each sensor becoming greater than one minute?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: A few comments: In general you never want to add a static delay as shown above when consideration of timing is concerned.  This is because code cannot guarantee that the hard coded value will work as designed under a stressed system, which is exactly what you are asking about.  Point #2, each socket is a unique ipaddress/port pair. So the receiving logic should have no problems identifying who's responding. You can't control response timings so why is there a wait anyway?  As far as thread safe this only applies to appending data to list just use locking to do that.

Comment: You really should be calling `EndReceive`. That's the only way you'll be notified of exceptions, and the only way you know how many bytes were received. Also, you'll need a separate `buffer_rcvr` for each sensor, because you could have multiple concurrent calls. Without separate receive buffers, they're going to clash. And I'll echo the previous comment's cautions against using static delays (i.e. `Thread.Sleep`).

Comment: First of all thanks for your advice! The delay was added under he impession that'd ensure the mandatory waits before asking for another response from the sensor, that's why it's placed right before sending the ACK message. I never even thougt that using a satic wait might be a problem, I will look up how to do it another way. I will add the EndReceive too.
As for the different buffer_rcvrs, is hat don b manually creating different threads or is there another way?
Once more, thank you for taking the time to read and answer!